# SimpleXML->asXML($filePath) failed to open stream permission denied

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a class that updates an xml file, however when it comes time to save the file I'm getting the error: SimpleXML->asXML($filePath) failed to open stream permission denied. I've never had this issue before and I can't find much of anything useful on the interwebs.

```
public static function CreateEntityConfig($database,$tables,$overwriteNodes = false) {
    if(!empty($database) && !empty($tables)) {
        $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        if(!$conn) { die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()); }

        // check to see if database node exists and overwrite if $overwriteNodes set to true
        // else create new database node 
        mysql_select_db($database);
        if(self::NodeExists('database',array('name',$database))) {
            if($overwriteNodes) {
                self::RemoveNode('database', array('name',$database));
            } else {
                die($database.' node already exists');
            }
        } else {
            //echo '<br>type='.get_class(self::$_xml);
            $databaseNode = self::AddNode(self::$_xml, 'Database', array('name' => $database));
        }
        $tableNode = self::AddNode($databaseNode, 'Table', array('name' => $tables));

        $result = mysql_query('select * from '.$tables);
        if(!$result) { die('Query failed: '.  mysql_error()); }

        $i = 0;
        while($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
            $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
            if($meta) {
                self::AddNode(
                    $tableNode,
                    'Field',
                    array(
                        'name' => $meta->name,
                        'not_null' => $meta->not_null,
                        'type' => $meta->type
                    )
                );
            } else {
                die('Unable to fetch meta information for '.$tables);
            }
            $i++;
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        //if(!self::$_xml->asXML()) { die('Unable save xml to file'); }
        echo self::$_xml->asXML(self::$_xmlFilePath);
    } else { die('Database and Table arguments required'); }
    mysql_close();
    echo self::$_xmlFilePath.' successfully built.';
}
```

Although Phil's answer was not exactly correct it helped me figure out the solution that worked for me. Here's an explanation of what I did - look at the first answer
https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux

thanks for any and all help,
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script does not have permission to write to whatever path is in `self::$_xmlFilePath`.

Without knowing more about your environment, it's hard to offer more advice.

Is it a Windows or Linux / Unix / Mac filesystem?

Which user is PHP running under?

Which user owns `self::$_xmlFilePath` and what are the permissions on that path?

**UPDATE**

I think your best bet, considering this looks like local development only, would be to make the destination folder world writable. You should be able to do this via Nautilus, or command line

```
chmod o+w /path/to/folder
```

Please note, this isn't a good solution for a production environment

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 11 and it's running under a user that has write access to that directory otherwise i wouldn't have been able to create the project.  Is it possible that the script is executed under a different user? The only two on my system are me and root

Comment: @bflemi3 Are you running it via the command line or browsing to a script on your web server? Also, I think you'll find there's a lot more than two users ;-)

Comment: @Phil browsing to a script through the browser. Oh, didn't know that - I'm new to ubuntu and linux in general. Thanks

Comment: @bflemi3 I think the default Ubuntu Apache user is `www-data`. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Also check whether .htaccess allows for access to specific directory. Remember that Basic Auth enabled makes accessing the folder to sometimes generate such issues.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions, I will check when i get back home.  I think this will work though.

Comment: I am going to give you credit for the answer because, although your exact solution didn't work it sent me down the correct path. I will update my post above with the solution the worked for me.  Thanks again Phil.